# Windows 7 homegroup networking name resolution problem

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have and odd problem with a 2 pc/netgear router small business network.

After a recent internet connection fault our folder shares stopped functioning.

Both PC's have the correct IP settings and can 'see' each other on the network, they both have internet access via the router and are in the same workgroup and homegroup. When you attempt to access a shared folder hosted on one machine from the other you get an alert saying 'windows cannot access \pc-name' dignostics reveal that 'windows can communicate with the name resolution but cannot find the hostname.

Neither computer can ping the other - any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this turned out to be the company's antivirus, ESET NOD32, being overactive and blocking network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IP adresses instead of hostname.

If it works that way you might have an issue with you DNS. Reset netgear router, flushdns entries from you workstation.

Then try again to open share with hostname

Comment: I don't think that I've ever seen a SOHO router that has DNS integrated. More likely than not it's using NetBIOS, not DNS.